# How to pass multiple (input) values onto query string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering how to pass multiple values onto a query string:

```html
<label class="btn active">

  <input
    type="radio"
    name="location"
    id="us"
    value="us"
    checked
  />

  US

</label>
```

The above code correctly passes `"us"` onto the query string.

```html
<label class="btn">
  <input type="radio" name="location" id="uk" value="uk" />
  UK
</label>
```

Radio button being passed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitButton").click(() => {
    const val = $("input[name=location]:checked").value();
  });
});
```

But if I would like to pass both parameters at the same time, what would be the solution?

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of your JavaScript too.

Comment: @AndrewL64 will update in a sec

Comment: How is your current JavaScript accessing the radio value?

Comment: How can a radio button select both?

Comment: Add complete html form please

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array as value:
US:

```
<label class="btn">
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          name="location"
                          id="both"
                          value="['us']"
                        />
                      </label>
```

UK:

```
<label class="btn">
                            <input
                              type="radio"
                              name="location"
                              id="both"
                              value="['uk']"
                            />
                          </label>
```

BOTH:

```
<label class="btn">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      name="location"
                      id="both"
                      value="['uk','us']"
                    />
                  </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the value from the radio and then just split it into two values using the [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method like this:

```js
const inputVal = document.querySelector('#both').value;
let countries = inputVal.split("&");
console.log(countries);
```

```html
<label class="btn">
  <input type="radio" name="location" id="both" value="us&uk" />Both
</label>
```

With the current jQuery approach that you are using, it would look something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitButton").click(() => {
    const val = $("input[name=location]:checked").value();
    const bothVals = val.split("&"); //bothVals consists of two items "uk" and "us" now
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers should be working, or you could just use `<input type='checkbox'>` so the user can select both values.